# migrate courier on Debian 10 to dovecot on Debian 11 with Froxlor

Tags: debian, postfix, dovecot, courier

I use [Froxlor][1] on a debian 10 server only to manage my customers email accounts. Installed is Courier 5.0.6 and postfix 3.4.23.

I plan this to first upgrade to Debian 11 then migrate to dovecot.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps:

##### Stop postfix and deinstall courier

```
systemctl stop postfix
systemctl stop courier-authdaemon
apt remove courier-authdaemon courier-imap courier-imap-ssl courier-pop courier-pop-ssl
```

#### Upgrade Debian

```
sed -i 's/buster\/updates/bullseye-security/g;s/buster/bullseye/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
apt update
apt dist-upgrade
```

#### Dovecot installation

```
apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d dovecot-mysql dovecot-managesieved dovecot-sieve
```

(Question: Do I need `dovecot-lmtpd`???)

#### import the Dovecot config templates

via the Froxlor web-configuration

#### migrate from courier 5.0.6 to Dovecot

using the tool [`courier-dovecot-migrate.pl`](https://github.com/rubo77/Dovecot-tools/blob/patch-1/courier-dovecot-migrate.pl) like described in the [README](https://github.com/rubo77/tools-1/blob/patch-1/README_courier-dovecot-migrate.pl.md):

```
./courier-dovecot-migrate.pl --to-dovecot --recursive /home/user/mail/
# if it runs fine:
# ./courier-dovecot-migrate.pl --to-dovecot --recursive --convert /home/user/mail/
```

#### Change in `10-mail.conf`:

```
#mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_location = maildir:~
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes   
}
```

#### add this in `/etc/postfix/master.cf`:

```
#Dovecot LDA
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe        flags=DRhu user=vmail:vmail argv=/usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -d ${recipient}
```

#### Add the certificate from courier to dovecot

add the same cert from `/etc/courier/imapd-ssl` in the line `TLS_CERTFILE=...` to your `conf.d/10-ssl.conf` file in `ssl_cert = <...` and `ssh_key = <...`

## possible problems:

- some Email folders could be not subscribed in your mail program any more

source: https://forum.netcup.de/administration-eines-server-vserver/vserver-server-kvm-server/8255-froxlor-courier-auf-dovecot-migrieren/